# How to change zoom icon while clicking image?

Tags: jquery, css

I am setting up a image which is when on clicked it is zoom-in and on seconds click it is zoom-out, while clicking the image i need to change cursor: zoom-in and cursor:zoom-out. is there any way to do this.`

```
  * { border:0; margin:0; padding:0; }
    p { position:absolute; top:3px; right:28px; color:#555; font:bold 
     13px/1 sans-serif;}

    /* these styles are for the demo, but are not required for the plugin */
    .zoom {
        display:inline-block;
        position: relative;
    }

    /* magnifying glass icon */
    .zoom:after {
        content:'';
        display:block; 
        width:33px; 
        height:33px; 
        position:absolute; 
        top:0;
        right:0;
        cursor:zoom-in;
    }

    .zoom img {
        display: block;
      cursor: -webkit-zoom-in;
        cursor: -moz-zoom-in;
    }

    .zoom-overlay-open, .zoom-overlay-transitioning {
    cursor: default;
    }
    .zoom img::selection { background-color: transparent; }

    #ex2 img:hover { cursor: url(grab.cur), default; }
```

Comment: Please click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55321556/edit), then `[<>]` snippet editor and produce a [mcve] - you can get free images from placeholder.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change cursor while clicking you can use pseudo-class :active

```
.zoom:active {
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

to keep it in the same mode while cursor on image use :hover

```
.zoom:hover {
    cursor: zoom-in;
}
```

Comment: But the `cursor` only stays active (zoomed-in) while you're holding the click.

Comment: @AndyHoffman Yes, you are right. This is a goal ("... while clicking the image i need to change cursor ..."), isn't it?

Comment: > `on clicked it is zoom-in and on seconds click it is zoom-out` This tells me that the states will persist until clicks happen.

Comment: it is working but the cursor only stays active (zoomed-in) while you're holding the mouse click, what if the image is zoomed-in and cursor is active even after not holding mouse click. Any suggestion?